# "onmouseover" displays the same message to all frames

Tags: javascript

I wonder how do each frame displays a different message. All frames are displaying the *MSG 1*. I wish each frame open when you hover on a word displayed a different message.

Thanks and sorry for bad english.

The code:

```
<html>
        <head>
                <title>Float Frames</title>
                <script>
                        function showLayer(obj){
                                var div = document.getElementById(obj).style;
                                div.display = "block";
                        }

                        function hideLayer(obj){
                                var div = document.getElementById(obj).style;
                                div.display = "none";
                        }
                </script>
                <style>
                        #divLayer{*css script*;}
                </style>
        </head>

        <body name="nm_body">
                <div>
                        <a href="LINK" onmouseover="showLayer('divLayer');" onmouseout="hideLayer('divLayer');">TEXT1</a>
                <div>
                <div id="divLayer" name="nm_divLayer">
                        MSG 1
                </div>

                <div>
                        <a href="LINK" onmouseover="showLayer('divLayer');" onmouseout="hideLayer('divLayer');">TEXT2</a>
                <div>
                <div id="divLayer" name="nm_divLayer">
                        MSG 2
                </div>
        </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't create more than one element with a given ID. That's invalid and that makes the bug.

You may use this for example :

```
<div>
        <a href="LINK" onmouseover="showLayer('divLayer1');" onmouseout="hideLayer('divLayer1');">TEXT1</a>
<div>
<div id="divLayer1" name="nm_divLayer">
        MSG 1
</div>

<div>
        <a href="LINK" onmouseover="showLayer('divLayer2');" onmouseout="hideLayer('divLayer2');">TEXT2</a>
<div>
<div id="divLayer2" name="nm_divLayer">
        MSG 2
</div>
```